# Service account identity from AppEngine to Cloud Function

Tags: google-app-engine, jwt, google-cloud-functions, google-iam

I have a private HTTP Google Cloud Function which I'd like to call from an AppEngine app in another project.

Ideally, the AppEngine Service Account would have `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker` on my Cloud Function, I'd turn off all other invokers, and I wouldn't have to worry about auth at all inside of the CF. I'm struggling to get the AppEngine identity passed along.

[Google's docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function) show how to do this from one Cloud Function to another, but AppEngine instead uses its own [identity library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/appidentity/AppIdentityService) to simplify getting access tokens. AppEngine docs outline:

- [Identity for other AppEngine apps in the same project](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_other_app_engine_apps)
- [Identity for Google APIs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_google_apis)
- Something seemingly unrelated: [verifying a payload's signature](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_third-party_services)

Any way to include the AppEngine identity such that Google's native Cloud Function `invoker` role will the request through?

Answer (score 0):

For this situation you will need to do the authentication programmatically by yourself.

First you need to add the app engine service account to the Cloud Functions permission.

After that, you need to follow the steps for [this situation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#service-to-function). Basically you will need to create a JWT, to authorize it and then to include the JWT in your request.
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#iap_make_request-python) you can find a code example for creating and authorising a JWT.

I have reproduced your situation in python. I used the code from the link I have sent to you, and then after I had my JWT alright, I made a request like this :

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  data = {'headers':      request.headers,
        'service_name': os.environ.get('GAE_SERVICE', '(running locally)'),
        'environment':  os.environ}
  return render_template('index.html', data=data)

@app.route('/request')
  def send_request():
     import requests
     receiving_function_url = 'YOUR-CLOUD-FUNCT-URL'
     r=requests.get("http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?audience="+receiving_function_url,
                headers={'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'})

     response = make_iap_request('YOUR-CLOUD-FUNCTION-URL', 'YOUR-CLOUD-FUNCTION-URL')

     print(response)

     return response




if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run('127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

The dependencies you need, in requirements.txt:

```
flask
PyJWT==1.7.1
cryptography==2.7
google-auth==1.6.3
gunicorn==19.9.0
requests==2.22.0
requests_toolbelt==0.9.1
```

In this [repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/iap) you can find more code examples on how to do IAP(Identity Aware Proxy) requests.